How do I apologize to a lecturer who told me not to ever call him again?
I recently sent a message to a lecturer concerning an issue I have. I asked him to advise me as he is not a lecturer in my department. We scheduled a call and during the call he said I was rude and lack phone etiquette and then he dropped the call. I called back to apologize but he told me not to ever call him again and blocked me on WhatsApp and on Facebook. I sent him an apology message in form of a text message. I really want to know if the apology message is enough.
Thanks to everyone who has given a reply… I will like to give more perspective
I saw my results some days back and it was a good result but I got a C in one of my courses and I was expecting an A but I am currently on internship so I am not on campus ground and I can not go and see the lecturer in charge of the course physically
I was confused on what to do and so that is why I message him on Facebook, he gave me his WhatsApp number… schedule a call with me and called me himself
During the call he asked me why I think I should have an A… I guess he was still trying to say something and I started talking and he immediately rebuked me and I was silent… when he went silent I then asked him if I can talk now and he just hanged up
To be sincere I was very confused on what happened and that was why I called him back and immediately he picked… he told me not to call him or reach out to him again if I don’t want issues with him and ask me to drop the call which I did….
After this I wrote a message apologizing sincerely and that was when I discovered he has blocked me both on WhatsApp and on Facebook…. I eventually have to send him a text message with another number of mine because I am Nigerian and respect for older people is a big deal here
I will not excuse my self as I knew I displayed bad phone etiquette but I really don’t understand him blocking me… I have been playing the events in my head and I do not think I did anything that a simple apology will not suffice for….
I really regret ever asking him for help… Most lecturers here are not approachable and the only reason why I messaged him was because of his constant post on Facebook about academics and all…
I really feel terrible about everything

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/

What exactly did you apologise for? Surely you did not send them a message apologising for messaging them.

If you're asking about etiquette, you should really tell us the routes by which you contacted the prof.  When you first sent the message to the lecturer, was it by routes specified for contact?

blocked me on WhatsApp and on Facebook I would argue that these are not appropriate channels for professional communication. In the future keep it to official channels sanctioned by the institute such as institute email, teams or office hours. Your institute should have a council service for student/academic staff relations if it is deemed serious enough.

@fdcpp I have learned that in some cultures, it's fairly normal to use WhatsApp between students and instructors. Not sure about Facebook.

@AzorAhai-him-: out of curiosity, which culture? Like certain fields, or certain countries?

@cag51 From conversations here and on Reddit, it seems to be a developing country thing. Which is easy to understand, if access to LMSes or a post-email culture might not have the same norms about emailing/texting.

I’m really confused: are you in their class (I assume then they’re at a different institution or in a different department), or did you cold contact someone with whom you have no affiliation? The answer will help us understand what’s going on here. If the former it sounds like the professor severely overreacted if you conveyed events accurately. If the latter, it sounds like their reaction could in part be b/c your contacting them in the first place was out of line.

@fdccp Whatsapp is absolutely used for professional communication world-wide. Should it be? I don't think so. But it is.

It baffles me somewhat that we've left this open. It's just not an academia question.

I've retagged this africa; I think that's a key part of this question. Unfortunately, very few of our "regulars" are from Africa (most are US/Europe), so you'll have to bear the cultural differences in mind.

"Can I talk now?" - I understand why you said that, namely to make sure you do not interrupt. However, the way it comes across is the following: You let the other person "let out their steam" and wait for them to finish, then say "Can I talk now?" - this sounds as if you did not listen, and just waited to make your point. Even while not intended, it can come across as very rude, namely as only interested in what you have to say. WhatsApp and the like are particularly tricky to navigate because of the significant synchronization delays which makes speaking over each other more likely than phone

"I eventually have to send him a text message with another number of mine" DON'T. That could be considered as harassment.

If you need some catharsis, leave a negative review on something like RateMyProfessors (also good place to check out their reputation there). No only is it a good place to vent, it warns others about their behaviour.

Whatsapp calls sometimes have a bit of lag (delay) - it's fairly common on such a call to hear what the other person has said a second or two after they've said it, especially if one of them is on a slow internet connection.  The result is people sound like they're interrupting each other. That might explain the "I guess he was trying to say something and I started talking". The lecturer might have been used to using Whatsapp within a campus (fast local connections, no lag) and misinterpreted your lag as rudeness.

@Parrotmaster don't get me wrong, the criticism for using a social media channel is levied at the academic, especially with the new information that they had graded student work. The academic has no right to block a student asking for grading clarification. If the academic felt the student's behaviour broke some code of conduct then that is a matter for the institute, not something the academic deals with by themselves. Regardless of its commonness in other cultures, using a social media channel for official communication is objectively bad practice. Commonplace is not a synonym of good

"I guess he was still trying to say something and I started talking and he immediately rebuked me" was that the first time you had interrupted them?

Don't. Bridge is burned.  Move on.


he told me not to ever call him again and blocked me on WhatsApp and on Facebook

This is an extremely clear sign that you should not try to contact this person again, and yet...

I sent him an apology message in form of a text message

This is also a breach of etiquette in this situation. When someone blocks you from contacting them through multiple avenues you should not take this as an invitation to try to find a loophole to contact them through. They are not challenging you to exhaust the list of possible communication venues and find a loophole in the instructions, they are telling you not to contact them.

I asked him to advise me as he is not a lecturer in my department….

It sounds like this person is not currently responsible for you in any way. Things might be different and you are required to interact with this person (for example, if they were teaching a class that you are taking). In that case, you may need to follow up through a third party to find out how to proceed. In your case, this is not necessary.
Overall, the lecturers' response sounds pretty extreme to me. It's possible that's because they've overreacted, or it's possible that you've been quite extremely out of line. Given your borderline-stalking attempts to contact them after being blocked, I'm encouraged to think in fact you may have been extremely out of line. If that's the case and you didn't realize it at the time, you really need to go over your conversation with someone else that you trust to find out what you've done wrong so you can avoid doing it again in the future.
Lastly, a word about apologies: a proper apology is for the person receiving the apology, not the one giving it. You are not owed forgiveness, you are not owed a chance to apologize or to save face or to not be thought of negatively in the future; the apology is not for you. You don't get to know if your apology is enough; if it's not enough, you don't get to make it bigger and better or somehow keep escalating until you are forgiven. You were told not to contact this person. What they want from you is to not contact them. If you actually care about what they want, you should not contact them. Any further attempts to apologize are selfish behaviors.

+1, though I would emphasize the part about the lecturer’s reaction being really extreme. While OP might want to consider improving their phone manners for future, I assume they didn’t do anything wildly inappropriate, in which case the lecturer handled this very poorly, and OP shouldn’t lose too much sleep over the incident.

@cag51 There is no information whatsoever what made the lecturer go to such an extreme mode. Without that information, no clear judgement can be made who did the most egregious contribution to the present situation. But the response is right. OP has been asked not to contact the lecturer. The lecturer has no responsibility whatsoever for OP. Thus, there is no meta-reason to try keep the channels open. Good response, upvoted.

For the lecturer's response to be appropriate, OP would have to have been intentionally disrespectful, which is difficult to square with the attempt to apologize and the post here. So, I would assume with 95% confidence that the lecturer is a jerk, or at least that they handled this poorly. But either way, leaving them alone is the right (indeed, only) thing to do at this point.

If OP is not the student of the lecturer's class, then it seems the lecturer has not obligation to respond. Why the lecturer has no freedom to refuse to communicate/talk to OP? Why he is a jerk in this case, and in particular OP is rude at the beginning?

@cag51 “For the lecturer's response to be appropriate, OP would have to have been intentionally disrespectful…” Nonsense. There are an infinite number of ways to monstrously insult a person without intentionality, and as many reasons why they may be disinclined or even unable to forgive it. An example: some deep trauma may have been triggered. Another: maybe they’re a minority and the OP was casually racist/sexist/whatever. It is wildly unfair to cast judgment on the lecturer… not least because the only perspective we have on them, and what happened, is the OP’s.

Not sure we will agree. If the (hypothetical) casual racism or triggering was intentional (or could only reasonably be assumed to be intentional), then fine. But if it could reasonably be assumed to be unintentional, then the lecturer should have assumed good faith and explained why they were offended. Particularly since OP seems to be the lecturer's student, not just some rando. Saying "never contact me again" and refusing to hear an apology is such an extremely extreme reaction that most people will only do it a few times (at most) in their career. Though this may vary culturally.

the apology is not for you → BTW in French the typical expression would be je m'excuse (=~ I am excusing me, incorrect and hints at the lack of Kinderstube) or excusez moi (=~ excuse me) --- instead of the correct (and more formal) je vous présente mes excuses (=~ I am presenting you my excuses) or veuillez m'excuser (~= please do it so that you excuse me, less nice), the former having the meaning of "I give you my excuses, and you may or may not accept them").  It may be old school today, as a kid in the 80's teachers were very strict about that (at least where I lived)

+1 We are teachers of professionalism, first and foremost, through our words and attitude, also with not our own students. These events may seem huge in a student's eyes, but, on the other side, you get to see much worse things. So I would not rule out the possibility that a toxic lecturer decided that saying no damages his own public image and needed a pretext. Learn the lesson and move on.

If X tells Y never to contact them again, does Y have an obligation to follow that demand? I don't think the answer is always yes. Perhaps X is being unreasonable, or perhaps X has an obligation towards Y that requires them to be in contact. Just because it is a drastic demand, which makes it sound like Y has behaved very badly towards X, does not mean that it always has to be respected.

@toby544 “Leave me alone” should always be respected. If there is some professional or other reason why you need to interact with the person regardless, the only correct thing to do is work through another party—their supervisor, assistant, colleague, whatever, or even get some higher power involved if necessary; never just forge ahead violating their explicit request that you don’t. Whether you feel a person is being unreasonable or not never gives you the right to violate their space, especially after they’ve clearly told you not to.. No means no. No always means no.

@indi I was talking about a hypothetical situation, not myself. And it was "don't contact me," not "leave me alone." But you are right that in those cases where Y needs to interact with X, even if Y thinks X is being unreasonable, they should do it through a third party.

I suspect that your message has to be enough if you are being blocked. One of you is in the wrong here and it is impossible at a distance to judge.
But examine your own phone etiquette for hints. There may be generational differences in how one treats such things as phone calls. You may need to be more formal than you think necessary.
FWIW, you were right to apologize. However, there is something to keep in mind about "apologies". I don't know whether this applies to you or not, but others might benefit:
An apology has a form something like "I'm sorry that I offended you with my behavior". But saying "I'm sorry you were offended by my behavior" isn't an apology at all. It is actually an insult. It has become common in political discourse lately, in fact, and is termed a "nopology".

I disagree with "you were right to apologize" in the context of the text message. The first attempt at apology was acceptable; after that, OP was told not to call again and blocked through messaging services. The right action in that situation is not to find an additional, unblocked avenue of contact.

@BryanKrause, you are making assumptions. I meant it in general terms.

@BryanKrause I would argue the student does have the right to email the  lecturer through their institute email. The staff do not have the right to block communications internal to the institute, but staff will have a channel to report inappropriate behaviour. I have had to block students myself from WhatsApp, not because they are overly rude or inappropriate, but  there is a difference to contacting someone socially (i.e. social media) or professionally (i.e. .edu email). Some students just didn't "get it" even after explaining, in that case it is best to shut down social channels.

@fdcpp Email was not mentioned as one of the communication strategies used. And it's not clear that this lecturer has any responsibility for the student (such as being their instructor).

it is perfectly viable to be sorry for the effect of something, without being sorry for taking the action, as in the offended was an unintentional victim of something necessary.

@Stian, yes, of course, but it isn't an apology.

@buffy Well, dismissing an apology that is genuinely sympathetic to your situation, but not remorseful of the actions that lead there is fine, but it isn't necessarily an insult.

@Stian, it is insulting when used when an apology is required. Parse it.

@BryanKrause Email was not mentioned that's sort of why I brought it up. It easy to forget that there are options outside of the ones presented, in particular modes of communication which an institute would insist on. I think it's unlikely that an institute would approve of WhatsApp / Facebook as an official channel to communicate.

I'd say an even better form of apology would simply be along the lines of “I'm sorry for behaving as I did.”  You could mention the offence it caused as well, but that's a secondary issue; the behaviour would still have been wrong even without it.

There are several layers of issue.

I really want to know if the apology message is enough.

You have tried to apologise. Using wrong channel at the time, but anyway, you have tried. Apology was not accepted and you were asked not to contact them at all.
Case closed. You have tried, it was not accepted. Life's going on.

We scheduled a call and during the call he said I was rude and lack phone etiquette and then he dropped the call. I called back to apologize...

We have no idea what happened and what insulted them so badly. Usually people can sustain some level of rudeness and lack of etiquette. Everyone has their limits different, of course.
You have insulted them on the phone and tried to phone again. How did you arrange the call? In person or via e-mail? You should have tried that channel instead.
Another details not provided:

When did you try to apologise? 2 seconds after the drop or the other day?
When did you call them? On scheduled time or with (substantial) delay?
How was the call long? 2 minutes or one hour?
How poignant were you in describing your issue? Were you telling detailed and emotional stories about your dying granny or you tried to go to the point directly?
What was the topic anyway? Was it about you personal issue with other member of the department (You know, departments are not isolated systems, people know each other at least from meeting day-by-day)?


I called back to apologize but he told me not to ever call him again

As already mentioned; how did you phrase your apology? "I'm sorry I (may have) (said something that) insulted you." is completely different than "I'm sorry you were insulted." The first puts the blame on you, the second puts the blame on them. Also, the phrasing and voice melody may have turned honest apology into sarcastic double strike.
There may be another layer: Are you a foreign student or native speaker? (For this purpose British English and American English are foreign languages)
It may happen that you use wrong phrase(s) that you understand differently as the professor does. Jokingly, my SO was kindly asked that "jo-jo" (yeah - yeah) and "dobře, bobře" (roger - badger(*)) are definitely not accepted answers to your senior when asked to do some task. They learned the meaning from interactions within my friends and family and extrapolated that to the workplace.
"We can murder some indian tonight" has completely different meaning between friends in London and in Houston.
You may have:

Promote to the first-name policy way too early
Use inappropriate or insulting phrase
You may have used wrong word that changed the whole meaning of the sentence
Formulate your question awkwardly or insultingly
Asked question way off the scheduled topic
Your voice melody, phrasing and rhythm may have changed meanings
You may have mispronounced their name, omit or add extra title (some are picky, some may be hurt by reminding of a title they couldn't reach, who knows?)

What to do to prevent such a situation?

Ask someone neutral and who you trust to re-iterate the call. Try to reiterate yourself as close to the call as possible. Discuss their feeling about the call. If you are foreign, ask someone local.
Ask someone (native) to discuss your speech. Word chioces, rhythm, intonation.
Don't call professors. Send e-mails or visit them in person (after the e-mail, preferably, or after the lecture or within their consulting hours). Phone can transmit sound real-time only. Your body language say much more than your words.

If you do your best to find why they were insulted and yet haven't find any reason, there is still a chance, the professor was just a d***s. Chances are non-zero but quite slim I'd like to say.

There may be one another issue. Sexism, but the other way. Many female students do try to impress the lecturers by their physical traits rather than skill. With my schoolmates we were calling such attempts as "breast out". It was humiliating and insulting, especially for those who didn't need to "breast out" to pass. We kept greatest respect to teachers that teased the "breastouts" until their desperate whisper "I'll do whatever you want to pass..." "What about studying, then? Next!"
Your approach to the lecturer and, again, your voice and wording might played "the poor little fragile girl" which they have seen soo many times before and are annoyed of already. Maybe worse. Maybe they fell for such a trap and now are avoiding any similar interaction in defence.

(*) "roger, [you] beaver" is word-by-word translation. Badger keeps the rhythm, though.

This is a good typology. But OP should not send an email. They have been asked not to and have already ignored it. They should not try again. It does not matter if the prof is a piece of work or OP committed a massive gaffe. Just don't. What OP can do is to ask a friend (or some trusted staff) where they may have made a mistake. OP must be very honest on what went on during that conversation, even if uncomfortable.

The emphasis was on the learning from the mistakes. That's why the official e-mail time delay and proff-read content. If the problem really was cultural misunderstanding and OP was a bit pushy it is the way to learn.

@CaptainEmacs Deleted the e-mail part. Especially when I read the question again and it was call, apology call, apology IM.
I've added one more reason for the instant block.

the professor was just a d***s → what does d***s mean? It is not "dick", it is not "dicks", "douchebag" does not fit either. It would be easier to just lift the spoilers for the non-native speakers here :) (we may learn something new too!) EDIT: "dumbass"?

@WoJ. I didn't want to say the word directly but you are absolutely right.

@Crowley it is not sensitive professional or personal information, or a movie spoiler so I am of the opinion that it does not need any blurring :) You forced me to write dick, dicks and douchebag instead! :) EDIT: not to mention that since I could not live without the full word I was about to also propose "dickass" but I do not know if the word exists in English

I'm posting an answer because I disagree strongly with the top response and I cannot post a comment. @Bryan Krause's answer is far too harsh on the OP and also diverts into some moralising, almost blaming the OP for seeking forgiveness.
The lecturer's response was probably extreme, but without knowing more detail it is impossible to say. As your senior at the university (and also in life), he probably should have given you an explanation of why he was so bothered, unless the matter was such as to make him very uncomfortable.
On your end, while it is completely understandable (and good) to want forgiveness, you should not let it get the better of you in cases like this where the other side is clearly not interested in having that conversation. You should leave the matter alone, unless it becomes necessary for you to interact with him in the future.
Consider what might have annoyed the professor and discuss with others that you trust to see if they might have some idea. But overall I would not lose too much sleep over this.

I think it's good to tell OP not to lose sleep over this, but they also absolutely should not pursue someone who has asked them to stop contact to offer more apologies.

One thing that is mysterious in the question is that there is no hint on what made the lecturer go no-contact. While I usually am sympathetic to students' plights, unless OP is a bit more explicit about what happened, there is the nagging uncertainty that they indeed committed some very serious breach of etiquette. I would encourage OP to give an idea what happened to avoid that impression. Until then, I think Bryan Krause's response covers the angles well.

If someone says not to contact them again, then weaselling around that with an "apology" is poor behaviour.

@BryanKrause Our view on what to do in this particular situation differs very little. The reason for my answer was to make clear to the OP (who I assume is very young) that not everyone shares your rigid and unsympathetic views on the ethics of apologies, so he/she should not take them for granted and suffer more guilt as a result.

@Enforce I would not describe my post as about the ethics of apologies but rather their sincerity. A sincere apology is acknowledging a wrong to the person wronged, but many people use apologies for themselves: they want to feel less guilty or to be forgiven. Those things do not help the person who is wronged. They also don't actually help the person who is in the wrong, because they're likely to offend the person they want to save face with. So, understanding the purpose of a sincere apology is to everyone's benefit.

@BryanKrause Yes, sincerity is important, but there is no reason to assume that it is lacking here.  In general, given the offender is sincere and the offence was not too severe, the wronged person must reasonably give the offender a chance to apologise, and a failure to forgive would be a shortcoming on behalf of the wronged and not the offender. Reading your answer one would think otherwise.

@Enforce The reason to think it's not sincere is that after the other person said extremely clearly "do not contact me", OP still contacted them. That shows that they are not primarily interested in what the person they wronged feels, because they are disregarding what the other person said they wanted ("do not contact me"). Alternatively, OP does not recognize that "do not call me"+blocking on two messaging venues communicates "do not contact me". Either way, OP is wrong to pursue further contact to attempt another apology.

I have dealt with difficult profs before, sometimes you have done nothing wrong, they were in a bad mood and you were a trigger of an outburst. Happens, many people in research lack social skills, and bad-tempered people are common in any workplace.
You should not care about what that person thinks, it has to do with him  and his issues, not you. What you may care about, though, is the C you were given, but only if this will affect your career in any way.
If you need to deal with an unfair grade, I would suggest contacting the ombudsperson. Otherwise, just walk away from anyone who is being unprofessional and a jerk.
